# How to use checkpoint model file in pytorch to test the CIFAR-10 dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

```
model = SqueezeNext()
model = model.to(device)

def load_checkpoint(model, optimizer, losslogger, filename='SqNxt_23_1x_Cifar.ckpt'):
# Note: Input model & optimizer should be pre-defined.  This routine only updates their states.
start_epoch = 0
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(filename))
    checkpoint = torch.load(filename)
    start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
    losslogger = checkpoint['losslogger']
    print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
              .format(filename, checkpoint['epoch']))
else:
    print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(filename))


return model, optimizer, start_epoch, losslogger

model, optimizer, start_epoch, losslogger = load_checkpoint(model, optimizer, losslogger)
```

---

> TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        41 test_loader   = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=80, num_workers=8, shuffle=False)
>        42 
>   ---> 43 model = SqueezeNext()
>        44 model = model.to(device)
>        45 def load_checkpoint(model, optimizer, losslogger, filename='SqNxt_23_1x_Cifar.ckpt'): TypeError: **init**() missing 3
>   required positional arguments: 'width_x', 'blocks', and 'num_classes'

I think I am not implementing this in right manner!!

Answer (score 0):

Your error isn't from your checkpoint function. If we look at the traceback:

```
> TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-51-94c8be648862> in <module>()
>      41 test_loader   = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=80, num_workers=8, shuffle=False)
>      42 
> ---> 43 model = SqueezeNext()
>      44 model = model.to(device)
>      45 def load_checkpoint(model, optimizer, losslogger, filename='SqNxt_23_1x_Cifar.ckpt'): TypeError: __init__() missing 3
> required positional arguments: 'width_x', 'blocks', and 'num_classes'
```

The line that we're being told is breaking the line 43:

```
> ---> 43 model = SqueezeNext()
```

And the error is:

```
> required positional arguments: 'width_x', 'blocks', and 'num_classes'
```

I'm assuming you're using [this implementation](https://github.com/luuuyi/SqueezeNext.PyTorch/blob/master/SqueezeNext.ipynb) of SqueezeNext, but whichever implementation you're using, you're not passing all the arguments needed to initialise the model. You'll want to change your code to something like:

```
model = SqueezeNext(width_x=1.0, blocks=[6, 6, 8, 1], num_classes=10)
```

If you're not using that implementation, you'll need to find the source code for the `SqueezeNext` model, and see what arguments the `__init__` function requires. You can try this:

```
import inspect

inspect.signature(SqueezeNext.__init__)
```

Which should give you the signature.

Comment: @RMPR Thanks for the edit. But note that “initialise” isn’t a typo, it’s correct British spelling.